# Is <body> of HTML ignored by Googlebot?

Tags: angular, google-search-console, googlebot, prerender

My goal is to let Googlebot crawl https://event.topoint.org/event/1.

My expected result is: I get content from google.com by querying `kesha site:event.topoint.org`.

My actual result: I get `Your search - kesha site:event.topoint.org - did not match any documents.`

Source Code (if this is required): https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/angular-structured-data-event-example

What I've tried:

1. Check in Google Search Console that the page is indexed.
2. In `<head>`, I add `<application type="application/ld+json>`

```
<head>
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"Event","id":"1","location":[{"@type":"VirtualLocation","url":"https://operaonline.stream5.com/"},{"@type":"Place","name":"Snickerpark Stadium","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","streetAddress":"100 West Snickerpark Dr","addressLocality":"Snickertown","postalCode":"19019","addressCountry":"US","addressRegion":"PA"}}],"name":"The Adventures of Kesha and Macklemore","startDate":"2023-12-16T12:45:53.743Z","description":"The Adventures of Kira and Morrison is coming to Snickertown in a can't miss performance.","endDate":"2023-12-17T12:45:53.743Z","eventAttendanceMode":"https://schema.org/MixedEventAttendanceMode","eventStatus":"https://schema.org/EventScheduled","image":["https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg","https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg","https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"],"offers":[{"@type":"Offer","availability":"https://schema.org/InStock","price":"30","priceCurrency":"USD","validFrom":"2023-12-15T12:45:53.743Z","url":"https://event.topoint.org/event/1"}],"organizer":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Kira and Morrison Music","url":"https://kiraandmorrisonmusic.com"},"performer":{"@type":"PerformingGroup","name":"Kira and Morrison"}}</script><style></style><script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"Event","id":"1","location":[{"@type":"VirtualLocation","url":"https://operaonline.stream5.com/"},{"@type":"Place","name":"Snickerpark Stadium","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","streetAddress":"100 West Snickerpark Dr","addressLocality":"Snickertown","postalCode":"19019","addressCountry":"US","addressRegion":"PA"}}],"name":"The Adventures of Kesha and Macklemore","startDate":"2023-12-16T12:45:53.743Z","description":"The Adventures of Kira and Morrison is coming to Snickertown in a can't miss performance.","endDate":"2023-12-17T12:45:53.743Z","eventAttendanceMode":"https://schema.org/MixedEventAttendanceMode","eventStatus":"https://schema.org/EventScheduled","image":["https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg","https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg","https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"],"offers":[{"@type":"Offer","availability":"https://schema.org/InStock","price":"30","priceCurrency":"USD","validFrom":"2023-12-15T12:45:53.743Z","url":"https://event.topoint.org/event/1"}],"organizer":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Kira and Morrison Music","url":"https://kiraandmorrisonmusic.com"},"performer":{"@type":"PerformingGroup","name":"Kira and Morrison"}}</script>
</head>
```

3. use Angular prerender by running the command `npx ng run event-topoint-org:prerender --no-guess-routes --routes-file src/routes.txt`.

```
<body>
<app-root _nghost-sc16="" ng-version="13.3.12" _nghost-serverapp-c5=""><a _ngcontent-serverapp-c5="" routerlink="/experiences" href="/experiences">Experiences</a> |
<a _ngcontent-serverapp-c5="" routerlink="/events" href="/events">Events</a><router-outlet _ngcontent-serverapp-c5=""></router-outlet><app-event-page _nghost-serverapp-c6=""><div _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 8px;"><p _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="">event-page works!</p><p _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="">id 1</p><p _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="">name The Adventures of Kesha and Macklemore</p><p _ngcontent-serverapp-c6="">description The Adventures of Kira and Morrison is coming to Snickertown in a can't miss performance.</p>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: By "ignore body" do mean do they see the content written into the body by JavaScript?  See [Do search engines perform JS rendering while crawling?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/140250/do-search-engines-perform-js-rendering-while-crawling)